# Understanding code with decorators in pymc, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators, pymc

I was trying to get some information on hierarchical models and found this awesome post: https://sl8r000.github.io/ab_testing_statistics/use_a_hierarchical_model/

In it, close the middle of the post, the author shares some code. There is the part I am having trouble with:

```
@pymc.stochastic(dtype=np.float64)
def hyperpriors(value=[1.0, 1.0]):
  a, b = value[0], value[1]
  if a <= 0 or b <= 0:
    return -np.inf
  else:
    return np.log(np.power((a + b), -2.5))

a = hyperpriors[0]
b = hyperpriors[1]
```

As you can see, the author uses `pymc`. Now, I am confused by the syntax here. I get the definition of the decorator, but not the definition of `a` and `b` with the square brackets. Does someone have experience in that domain and would mind to share what is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pymc project uses decorators not to return a new function, but to return a [`Stochastic()` class instance](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#the-stochastic-class).

From the documentation:

> Uniformly-distributed discrete stochastic variable `switchpoint` in (*disaster_model*) could alternatively be created from a function that computes its log-probability as follows:
>
> ```
> @pymc.stochastic(dtype=int)
> def switchpoint(value=1900, t_l=1851, t_h=1962):
>     """The switchpoint for the rate of disaster occurrence."""
>     if value > t_h or value < t_l:
>         # Invalid values
>         return -np.inf
>     else:
>         # Uniform log-likelihood
>         return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)
> ```
>
> Note that this is a simple Python function preceded by a Python expression called a **decorator** [vanRossum2010], here called `@stochastic`. Generally, decorators enhance functions with additional properties or functionality. The `Stochastic` object produced by the `@stochastic` decorator will evaluate its log-probability using the function `switchpoint`. The value argument, which is required, provides an initial value for the variable. The remaining arguments will be assigned as parents of `switchpoint` (*i.e.* they will populate the parents dictionary).

So `hyperpriors` is an instance of the `Stochastic` class, and it is that object that supports indexing. Thus you can use `hyperpriors[0]` and `hyperpriors[1]` on that object. `hyperpriors` is *not* a function anymore.

Comment: Ok, so the stochastic class has the property to return the updated variables passed into value. So, in my case: a = hyperpriors[0] and
b = hyperpriors[1]. In your case, I would have year = switchpoint[0]. The model fits the variables depending on the specified distributions and in my case hyperpriors. The variables stored internally (inside the stochastic class) are then accessed as indexes of the instance hyperprior and set to a and b. I think that makes more sense now. Thanks!